# latitude and longitude values giving null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am a newcomer for android programming and stack overflow. MY problem here is mylongitudey in onclick method is giving null value. I have 3 activities.Below one is one among them. I want the latitude and longitude from google map and to send those points into another activity. The main problem here is, it is not giving the latitude and longitude value instead Toasting null value. I couldn't find what was the mistake . Can anyone help me? Thanks in advanced.

```
SharedPreferences points;
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

Address returnedAddress;

double mylongitudey,mylatitudey;
String latilongi;
ImageView iv;
Button manual,proceed;

GoogleMap map;
LatLng mylat ;

String latlong;
Marker mymarker;
boolean markerclicked;
double mylatitudeyd,mylongitudeyd;
String addstringaa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.two_buttons);
  actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


  Toast.makeText(this,"Please select the destination by long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  LatLng mylat;
  final GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
  map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
  map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
 // map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);

  SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("map", 0);
  String mylats = (shared.getString("twolati", "NoValue"));
  String mylong= (shared.getString("twolong", "NoValue"));
  double dmylats = Double.valueOf(mylats);
  double dmylong = Double.valueOf(mylong);
   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
  mylat = new LatLng(dmylats, dmylong);
  try {
  Toast.makeText(this, "This is"+mylats,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"problem in mylat",0);
    e.printStackTrace();
}


 map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylat, 13));
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mylat).title("You are Here"));

 markerclicked=false;
  //onMyLocationButtonClick();
  map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(markerclicked==false)
        {
         mymarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).title("Your Destination").draggable(true));
         markerclicked=true;
    }else{

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Marker Aready Set..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    }
});


  map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
    LatLng mylatlong;
    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mylongitudey = arg0.getLongitude();
        mylatitudey = arg0.getLatitude();
        mylatlong = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0.getLongitude());
        //sourcepoint=String.format(" ",mylat);

//  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylat,1));
         map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylatlong, 14));


    }
});


 //   Toast.makeText(this, getmapid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

SharedPreferences pr= getSharedPreferences("reserve", 0);
latilongi=pr.getString("sourcepoint", "sourcepoint");

manual=(Button)findViewById(R.id.manuel);
manual.setOnClickListener(this);

proceed=(Button)findViewById(R.id.proceed);
proceed.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {



    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionmenu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getTitle(),
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        if (getParentActivityIntent() == null) {
            Log.i("tag", "You have forgotten to specify the parentActivityName in the     AndroidManifest!");
            onBackPressed();
        } else {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;

    case R.id.action_refresh:
        // refresh

        Intent intent = new Intent(Drop_Off_Location.this, Main.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



        try {
             if (v.getId() == R.id.proceed) {
                /* Toast.makeText(this, "address"+mylongitudey, 0);
                 Toast.makeText(this, " destination in DOL class "+addstringaa, 0).show();*/
                 points= getSharedPreferences("map", 0);
                 ed=points.edit();
                 String twolatitudey = String.valueOf(mylatitudey);
                 String twolongitudey = String.valueOf(mylongitudey);                                        
                 ed.putString("twolatitudey",twolatitudey);
                 ed.putString("twolongitudey", twolongitudey);                   
                 ed.commit();
                 Toast.makeText(this, "dest longitude"+mylongitudey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Drop_Off_Location.this,Autofill.class);
                 startActivity(intent); 

            }
             else if(v.getId()==R.id.manuel)
             {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Drop_Off_Location.this,Reserve.class);
                    startActivity(intent);                   
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             Toast.makeText(this,"error in onclick"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**Logcat verbose:**

```
10-08 02:23:53.965: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 25% free 7167K/9528K, paused 132ms, total 134ms
10-08 02:23:53.975: I/dalvikvm-heap(3221): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.411MB for 2457616-byte allocation
10-08 02:23:54.145: D/dalvikvm(3221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 20% free 9565K/11932K, paused 167ms, total 167ms
10-08 02:23:55.895: W/System.err(3221): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
10-08 02:23:55.895: W/System.err(3221):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at jasperit.atlcitylimo.Autofill.onCreate(Autofill.java:189)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-08 02:23:55.905: W/System.err(3221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 02:23:55.915: W/System.err(3221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 02:23:55.915: W/System.err(3221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-08 02:23:55.915: W/System.err(3221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-08 02:23:55.915: W/System.err(3221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 02:23:56.015: W/System.err(3221): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
10-08 02:23:56.015: W/System.err(3221):     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
10-08 02:23:56.035: W/System.err(3221):     at jasperit.atlcitylimo.Autofill.onCreate(Autofill.java:227)
10-08 02:23:56.035: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-08 02:23:56.035: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-08 02:23:56.045: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-08 02:23:56.045: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-08 02:23:56.045: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-08 02:23:56.045: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-08 02:23:56.045: W/System.err(3221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-08 02:23:56.045: W/System.err(3221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 02:23:56.085: W/System.err(3221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-08 02:23:56.085: W/System.err(3221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 02:23:56.085: W/System.err(3221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 02:23:56.085: W/System.err(3221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-08 02:23:56.095: W/System.err(3221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-08 02:23:56.095: W/System.err(3221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 02:23:56.255: I/Choreographer(3221): Skipped 688 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-08 02:23:57.585: I/Choreographer(3221): Skipped 267 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-08 02:23:58.885: I/Choreographer(3221): Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-08 02:23:59.675: I/Choreographer(3221): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//instance variables
 private GoogleMap googleMap;
 private double longitude = 0.0;
 private double latitude = 0.0;
 private LocationManager locationManager = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   // your layout
  try {
    initilizeMap();     

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);   
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

   }
 } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }


 private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();    //provide your id       

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       longitude = location.getLongitude();
      latitude = location.getLatitude();
      //System.out.println(latitude+ " "+longitude );
      if(!isStopFocusEnabled){
          CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(12).build(); 
          googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
       }


}
```

In Manifest below code must be there

```
      <permission
    android:name="com.ani.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.ani.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />



<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR KEY" />

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

// Change it accordingly.... it will definitely work...

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int X = (int)event.getX();          
    int Y = (int)event.getY();

    GeoPoint geoPoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(X, Y);
}
```

Comment: Please describe your answer.